# How do you refresh a filter view in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Right now it seems like the easiest way to refresh a filter view in google sheets is to remove the filter view and then apply it again. What is the fastest way to refresh a filter view in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click the filter button in the first row of any column (it does not have to be a column that is actually filtered), then click 'OK' it will refresh the filter.

Comment: this doesn't re-sort the rows

Comment: It's not intended to resort the rows, just refresh any filters.

Comment: Doesn't refresh sorting in the filter view. Sorting is an integral part of the feature so this answer is partial at best

Comment: @watsonic Unfortunately, unless something has changed in the time since I wrote this, it's less a deficit in the answer than it is a deficit in Sheets ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:  Apply the filter to the entire column / sheet instead of just the current selection.  This will automatically update all of the filters to include new additions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to resort based on the existing filter after you have changed some of the sorted values, use the F5 key.

Answer (score -1):

In MacOS Chrome, browser refresh doesn't work while the focus is in your sheet.

One way to get around it: put the cursor in the URL bar (shortcut in MacOS Chrome: Command-L). Then you can browser refresh (in MacOS Chrome: Command-R) and it will refresh the view .

Note: in other browsers or other OS's these shortcuts will be different.